# Mount smb3 folder with SmbServerNameHardeningLevel=2

Tags: cifs, smb

### TLDR:

Is the `mount.smb3` command compatible with Windows endpoints with the policy `SmbServerNameHardeningLevel` set to 2? How can I make it work?

---

### Description of the error:

I am on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 trying to mount a samba folder that resides on a Windows 11 machine but I keep getting errors `mount error(13): Permission denied`

The command I am using is:

```
sudo mount.smb3 //IP4ADDRESS/FOLDER_NAME /mnt/target/ -o credentials=~/.smbcredentials
```

The credentials file contains

```
username=MyUser
password=TheSecr3t
workgroup=WORKGROUP
```

When I look at the Event Viewer on the target machine, I can see that the connection is being denied due to a policy set by the admin of the Windows 11 machine: `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\SmbServerNameHardeningLevel` with value set to `2`.

```
Error de autenticación de sesión SMB (SMB session authentication error)

Nombre de cliente (Name of client): \\IP4ADDRESS
Dirección de cliente (Address of client): IP4ADDRESS:50302
Nombre de usuario (Username): MyUser
Id. de sesión (Session ID): 0xB80010000035
Estado (Status): {Acceso denegado} (Access Denied)
Un proceso ha solicitado acceso a un objeto, pero no se le han concedido esos derechos de acceso. (0xC0000022) / A process has requested access to an object, but it was not granted access rights (0xC0000022)
SPN: 
Directiva de validación de SPN (SPN validation directive): SPN required / validate full
```

---

### What I've tried and what I know:

I know the error is **NOT** an obvious issue such as the permissions of `/mnt/target`, the credentials I am using, or the setup of the shared folder. How?

- If I ask the admin of the Windows 11 machine to temporarily downgrade `SmbServerNameHardeningLevel` to `1` through the registry, the `mount.smb3` command works perfectly! This is, however, not an option as that downgrade will be overwritten by a global security policy every once in a while.
- If I use `gio` as an alternative mounting mechanism, it works OK!

```
echo -e "MyUser\nWORKGROUP\nTheSecre3t" | gio mount smb://IP4ADDRESS/FOLDER_NAME
```

The problem I have with this is that the mount is only visible to the mounting user because it is available under `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs` - I want to give all the users of the Ubuntu machine access to the mounted location.

- Given that I have a case that works and a case that doesn't, I've used wireshark to packet capture both cases and I can see that the `gio` command that works, aside from using GSSAPI, is sending a `Target Name` attribute as part of the NTLMv2 response, while the `mount.smb3` command isn't, and I am pretty sure that's why the latter is not working when the security policy is set to `2`.

---

Here's the screenshot of the packet capture of the `gio` command that **DOES** work.

[image: Packet capture of gio that works]

And here's the one with `mount.smb3` that **DOES NOT**

[image: Packet capture of mount.smb3 that does not work]

#### *If* I am right, I guess the question becomes, how can I force `mount.smb3` to send the SPN?

---

#### More literature:

These links seem to confirm what I've described, but I can't find a fix. GSSAPI seems to support SPN correctly, and that's why `gio` works.

- https://github.com/gssapi/gss-ntlmssp/issues/67#issuecomment-1068512627
- https://github.com/jborean93/smbprotocol/issues/169#issuecomment-1067860089
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1096156/why-does-a-ms-gpo-option-break-smb-shares-that-use-a-hosts-file-for-the-machine
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/dns-cname-alias-cannot-access-smb-file-server-share

---

**PS:** I have tried using DNS names instead of IP addresses because I've read multiple times that such a detail can affect the way NTLM is negotiated, but that doesn't seem to work anyway.

Any help appreciated. Thanks for the time you've spent reading this entry.

Comment: Alternatively: Anybody knows how to share the FUSE mountpoint created by `gio` so that all users can access it?